# How do I prevent Bootstrap from pushing a column down?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, push

I looked several times on SO and while it may be a repeat question, all of the answers to the previously asked questions did not work. Hence why I'm posting this one. It's a classic Bootstrap grid problem. I would like 3 columns of thumbnail images in Bootstrap. However, when I include a lot of text on one of the columns, it pushes the remainder down. I tried a clearfix class to prevent this, but no dice. Does anyone know a solution? Thanks.

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img class="featured-image" src="img/hd-wallpapers-1920x1080.jpeg" alt="...">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                            <p> Lorem Ipsum. Text that is pushing the columns down.</p>
                            <div class="ratings-section">
                                <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp">Read More</button></p>
                                <p class="star-rating">
                                    Editors Rating:
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img class="featured-image" src="img/hd-wallpapers-1920x1080.jpeg" alt="...">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                            <p> Lorem Ipsum</p>
                            <div class="ratings-section">
                                <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp">Read More</button></p>
                                <p class="star-rating">
                                    Editors Rating:
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img class="featured-image" src="img/hd-wallpapers-1920x1080.jpeg" alt="...">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                            <p> Lorem Ipsum</p>
                            <div class="ratings-section">
                                <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp">Read More</button></p>
                                <p class="star-rating">
                                    Editors Rating:
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img class="featured-image" src="img/hd-wallpapers-1920x1080.jpeg" alt="...">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                            <p> Lorem Ipsum</p>
                            <div class="ratings-section">
                                <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp">Read More</button></p>
                                <p class="star-rating">
                                    Editors Rating:
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img class="featured-image" src="img/hd-wallpapers-1920x1080.jpeg" alt="...">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                            <p> Lorem Ipsum</p>
                            <div class="ratings-section">
                                <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp">Read More</button></p>
                                <p class="star-rating">
                                    Editors Rating:
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img class="featured-image" src="img/hd-wallpapers-1920x1080.jpeg" alt="...">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
                            <p> Lorem Ipsum</p>
                            <div class="ratings-section">
                                <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp">Read More</button></p>
                                <p class="star-rating">
                                    Editors Rating:
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fiddle or a screenshot please.

Comment: My score is not high enough to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing the float on your columns is the way to do this, the solution depends on what your ultimately implementing though. If you're going to be generating these columns at random I would use the first solution. If you only have a limited amount of these columns that will remain static (or you can easily generate the HTML to accompany them) then the build in help classes will work.

Hopefully these examples help or get you headed in the right direction.

**Example 1**: Add your own CSS to clear the columns.

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .item:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 991px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  .item:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="featured-image" src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum 1</h3>

          <p>Lorem Ipsum. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns
            down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down.</p>
          <div class="ratings-section">
            <p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp">Read More</button>
            </p>
            <p class="star-rating">Editors Rating: <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>

            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="featured-image" src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum 2</h3>

          <p>Lorem Ipsum Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down.</p>
          <div class="ratings-section">
            <p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp">Read More</button>
            </p>
            <p class="star-rating">Editors Rating: <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>

            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="featured-image" src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum 3</h3>

          <p>Lorem Ipsum Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down.
            Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text
            that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down.</p>
          <div class="ratings-section">
            <p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp">Read More</button>
            </p>
            <p class="star-rating">Editors Rating: <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>

            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="featured-image" src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum 4</h3>

          <p>Lorem Ipsum Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down.</p>
          <div class="ratings-section">
            <p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp">Read More</button>
            </p>
            <p class="star-rating">Editors Rating: <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>

            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="featured-image" src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum 5</h3>

          <p>Lorem Ipsum Text that is pushing the columns down.</p>
          <div class="ratings-section">
            <p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp">Read More</button>
            </p>
            <p class="star-rating">Editors Rating: <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>

            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="featured-image" src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum 6</h3>

          <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <div class="ratings-section">
            <p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp">Read More</button>
            </p>
            <p class="star-rating">Editors Rating: <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>

            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="featured-image" src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum 7</h3>

          <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <div class="ratings-section">
            <p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp">Read More</button>
            </p>
            <p class="star-rating">Editors Rating: <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>

            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="featured-image" src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum 8</h3>

          <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down.
            Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text
            that is pushing the columns down.</p>
          <div class="ratings-section">
            <p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp">Read More</button>
            </p>
            <p class="star-rating">Editors Rating: <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>

            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="featured-image" src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum 9</h3>

          <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <div class="ratings-section">
            <p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp">Read More</button>
            </p>
            <p class="star-rating">Editors Rating: <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>

            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Example 2**: Use the helper [reset](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) classes from Bootstrap

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="featured-image" src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum 1</h3>

          <p>Lorem Ipsum. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns
            down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down.</p>
          <div class="ratings-section">
            <p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp">Read More</button>
            </p>
            <p class="star-rating">Editors Rating: <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>

            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="featured-image" src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum 2</h3>

          <p>Lorem Ipsum Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down.</p>
          <div class="ratings-section">
            <p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp">Read More</button>
            </p>
            <p class="star-rating">Editors Rating: <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>

            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="featured-image" src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum 3</h3>

          <p>Lorem Ipsum Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down.
            Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text
            that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down.</p>
          <div class="ratings-section">
            <p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp">Read More</button>
            </p>
            <p class="star-rating">Editors Rating: <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>

            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-md-block visible-lg-block"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="featured-image" src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum 4</h3>

          <p>Lorem Ipsum Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down.</p>
          <div class="ratings-section">
            <p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp">Read More</button>
            </p>
            <p class="star-rating">Editors Rating: <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>

            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="featured-image" src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum 5</h3>

          <p>Lorem Ipsum Text that is pushing the columns down.</p>
          <div class="ratings-section">
            <p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp">Read More</button>
            </p>
            <p class="star-rating">Editors Rating: <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>

            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="featured-image" src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum 6</h3>

          <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <div class="ratings-section">
            <p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp">Read More</button>
            </p>
            <p class="star-rating">Editors Rating: <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>

            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-md-block visible-lg-block"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="featured-image" src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum 7</h3>

          <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <div class="ratings-section">
            <p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp">Read More</button>
            </p>
            <p class="star-rating">Editors Rating: <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>

            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="featured-image" src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum 8</h3>

          <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down.
            Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text that is pushing the columns down. Text
            that is pushing the columns down.</p>
          <div class="ratings-section">
            <p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp">Read More</button>
            </p>
            <p class="star-rating">Editors Rating: <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>

            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 item">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="featured-image" src="http://placehold.it/1920x1080" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum 9</h3>

          <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</p>
          <div class="ratings-section">
            <p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg sharp">Read More</button>
            </p>
            <p class="star-rating">Editors Rating: <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
              <i class="fa fa-star"></i>

            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked. Appreciate the help!